# Repeating watermark php

Tags: php, image-manipulation, watermark

I am using [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) image manipulation library this library in a project and I am stuck on adding watermark image all over the source image.

Is it possible to repeat the watermark image on all over the source image like in the following example?

[image: stock-photo-79576145-old-room]

I try the following code, but it doesn't work for me.

```
$thumbnail = $manager->make($name);
$watermark = $manager->make($watermarkSource);
$x = 0;

while ($x < $thumbnail->width()) {
    $y = 0;

    while($y < $thumbnail->height()) {
        $thumbnail->insert($watermarkSource, 'top-left', $x, $y);
        $y += $watermark->height();
    }

    $x += $watermark->width();
}

$thumbnail->save($name, 80);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just solved this problem  via Intervention Image library using it in Laravel Framework. So here's code snippet.

```
public function watermarkPhoto(String $originalFilePath,String $filePath2Save ){

    $watermark_path='photos/watermark.png';
    if(\File::exists($watermark_path)){

        $watermarkImg=Image::make($watermark_path);
        $img=Image::make($originalFilePath);
        $wmarkWidth=$watermarkImg->width();
        $wmarkHeight=$watermarkImg->height();

        $imgWidth=$img->width();
        $imgHeight=$img->height();

        $x=0;
        $y=0;
        while($y<=$imgHeight){
            $img->insert($watermark_path,'top-left',$x,$y);
            $x+=$wmarkWidth;
            if($x>=$imgWidth){
                $x=0;
                $y+=$wmarkHeight;
            }
        }
        $img->save($filePath2Save);

        $watermarkImg->destroy();
        $img->destroy(); //  to free memory in case you have a lot of images to be processed
    }
    return $filePath2Save;
}
```

If you use PHP version prior to 7 remove String type declaration from function arguments. just make it

```
    public function watermarkPhoto($originalFilePath, $filePath2Save ){....}
```

Also if you are not using Laravel Framework and you don't have File class included just remove redundand check from function.

```
      if(\File::exists($watermark_path))
```

So the simplest framework-agnostic function would be:

```
function watermarkPhoto($originalFilePath, $filePath2Save ){

        $watermark_path='photos/watermark.png';
        $watermarkImg=Image::make($watermark_path);
        $img=Image::make($originalFilePath);
        $wmarkWidth=$watermarkImg->width();
        $wmarkHeight=$watermarkImg->height();

        $imgWidth=$img->width();
        $imgHeight=$img->height();

        $x=0;
        $y=0;
        while($y<=$imgHeight){
            $img->insert($watermark_path,'top-left',$x,$y);
            $x+=$wmarkWidth;
            if($x>=$imgWidth){
                $x=0;
                $y+=$wmarkHeight;
            }
        }
        $img->save($filePath2Save);

        $watermarkImg->destroy();
        $img->destroy();

    return $filePath2Save;
}
```

Also you need watermark image in png format with transparent background.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, My code was working just fine, when I was tested there was a problem with the "imagick" driver and later I found it's just working fine. Still, I'm using that in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just adding one thing added to your accepted answer when you try your code and the above-accepted code, the watermark on the images will be very close together and close together with what I tried. like this

[image]

So if you want the watermarks like what you want, you need to modify the code with plus numbers on wmarkheight and wmarkwidth like this:

```
while ($x < $imgWidth) {
            $y = 0;

            while($y < $imgHeight) {
                $imgFileCollection->insert($watermark, 'top-left', $x, $y);
                $y += $wmarkHeight+30;
            }

            $x += $wmarkWidth+40;
        }
```

this line of code is important:

```
$y += $wmarkHeight+30;
$x += $wmarkWidth+40;
```

and you will get the result like that below:

[image]

Comment: desperately looking for this ans